# How do you sort array of arrays in c#?

Tags: c#, arrays, .net

I'm trying to sort a list of `intervals` based on start time (which is the first element).

```
public static int[][] SortIntervals(int[][] intervals)
{
    intervals.Sort(Comparer<int[]>.Create((a, b) => a[0].CompareTo(b[0]))); // error
    return intervals;
}
```

> Error -CS1503 Argument 1: cannot convert from 'System.Collections.Generic.Comparer<int[]>' to 'System.Array'

I can sort a list of intervals just fine, maybe I'm missing the correct syntax for it.

```
public static List<int[]> SortIntervals(List<int[]> intervals)
{
    intervals.Sort(Comparer<int[]>.Create((a, b) => a[0].CompareTo(b[0])));
    return intervals;
}
```

Comment: `Array.Sort(intervals, (a, b) => a[0].CompareTo(b[0]));`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are right, in case of array you should use *different syntax* [Array.Sort](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.array.sort?view=net-6.0#system-array-sort-1(-0()-system-comparison((-0)))):

```
public static int[][] SortIntervals(int[][] intervals)
{
    if (null == intervals)
        throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(intervals));

    Array.Sort(intervals, (a, b) => a[0].CompareTo(b[0]));    

    return intervals;
}
```

Comment: Great, thank you!